# Вывод курсора Sqlite в одну строку TreeView

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3, treeview

Ваша прошлая помощь мне очень помогла! Спасибо!
Сейчас возникла новая проблема. Наверняка кто-то уже сталкивался.
Есть курсор, который получает данные одного столбца из sqlite. Я его вывожу в TreeView. И он как и положено выводит эти данные в одну колонку в несколько строк. Мне же надо получать строки из курсора и выводить их в разные колонки Treeview.

Делаю так (упрощенно):

```
        self.tree1_6 = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=(
            '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'),show='headings')

        self.tree1_6.column('01', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.column('02', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.column('03', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.column('04', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.column('05', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.column('06', width=70, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree1_6.heading('01', text='Январь')
        self.tree1_6.heading('02', text='Февраль')
        self.tree1_6.heading('03', text='Март')
        self.tree1_6.heading('04', text='Апрель')
        self.tree1_6.heading('05', text='Май')
        self.tree1_6.heading('06', text='Июнь')
        self.tree1_6.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan = 3)
        # SQLITE подключена ранее
        self.c1 = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c1.execute(
            'SELECT summa_ FROM total WHERE year_=?',(int(select_year),))
        [self.tree1_6.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.c1.fetchmany(size=6)]
```

По логике заменил values=row на values=self.tree1_6.column и получил
[image: Ошибка]

Так как я только учусь Питону, то прошу помочь в этом вопросе. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666358/how-to-output-sqlite3-data-in-tkinter-treeview

Comment: Это не совсем то. Тут построчно выводится база. У меня же основная таблица базы состоит из 3х столбцов и N-количества строк. Запрос по условию выбирает данные одного столбца. Курсор состоит из одного столбца и N-количества строк. Мне надо 6 первых строк курсора разместить в 6ти столбцах Treeview в одной строке.